# Sorting in linear time using Trie data structure

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sorting

I have written an article on a new way of non comparison sorting and I want it to get peer reviewed. The sorting algorithm uses Trie data structure to store digits of numbers as nodes and iterating over each node 10 times (k) in a depth first traversal returns the sorted list. Time complexity O(n log m), log to the base k given a list of 'n' numbers in base 'k' and 'm' digits in the highest number in the list. 'm' doesn't depend on 'n'. Kinda like radix sort but still different. I'm pretty sure the solution can be improved a lot or not be legit at all, hence I am trying to reach out to people who can help me on this. Can you please take a look at it and give me your feedback?

Medium Article : https://medium.com/@jo07/triesort-in-linear-time-be1d07d41679

Github repo : https://github.com/jo07/Trie-Sort

Jo,

Cheers.

Comment: It is worth to compare the running time for arrays of, say 1000, 10000, 100000 and 1000000 integers, including the conversions to digits and back, to that of QuickSort (without conversions). Also getting an estimate of the space complexity, in bytes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you for your comments. There is scope of improvement, like the base could be 2 so we don't have to loop through 0 to 9 as in for base 10. We can use the integer values to built the trie instead of converting to string and back. Will definitely try running time for small to large array sizes.

Comment: Yep. This increases the length of the number representations by a factor 3.3. Better consider base 8 or 16.

Comment: (See also: [Jomy Sebastian@CR: Sorting in linear time using Trie Data Structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/274943/93149).)

Comment: How is this different from a [radix tree or critbit tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)? Or is your idea just to use a trie for sorting data?

Comment: Unfortunately, providing peer review for a paper is beyond the scope of this web site.  That is more work than can reasonably be expected from a question here.  We are looking for objectively answerable technical questions about computer science.  Also, we ask that questions be self-contained.